# @sentry/serverless module doesn't report Firebase functions unhandled errors

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, sentry

I'm trying to integrate Sentry into our set of Firebase functions and I'm following their instruction for GCP functions:

```js
Sentry.init({
    dsn: config.SENTRY_DSN,
    environment: config.ENVIRONMENT,
    tracesSampleRate: 1.0,
});

export const myFunction = Sentry.GCPFunction.wrapHttpFunction(
    functions.region('europe-west1').https.onRequest(myFunctionHandler),
);

function myFunctionHandler() {
    // throw new Error('Unhandled Sentry test event');
    try {
        throw new Error('Handled node Sentry test event');
    } catch (e) {
        Sentry.captureException(e);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the handled exception is caught but the unhandled one isn't caught by Sentry. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Are Firebase functions and GCP functions interchangeable in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, [Sentry's GCP Functions integration](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/node/guides/gcp-functions/) is not fully compatible with Firebase Cloud Functions. There are [workarounds](https://medium.com/qualdesk/how-to-capture-typescript-firebase-functions-errors-in-sentry-d6984951ed9) though.